# JavaScript interpreter (ES2015 support)

Tags: javascript, abstract-syntax-tree, interpreter

I'm trying to build a JavaScript "visualizer" app, so i need some static and dynamic information.

For example given this code snippet:

```
class Foo{
 constructor(prop){
   this.props = prop;
 }
}
const x = new Foo('prop');
```

I would like to be able to "step" through that code and get a sort of an AST including the call-stack, variable environment and results of the function calls.

Parsing it with acorn or other parsers will give me the static AST which is great but obviously won't provide the dynamic information i need like call-stack (when invoking a function) and the returned values etc.

I've used [JS-Interpreter](https://github.com/NeilFraser/JS-Interpreter) and its exactly what i need, but only later i found out it lacks support for ES2015 features, which is a deal breaker for me. I thought maybe run my ES2015 code through `babel.transform` and pass the transformed ES5 code to [JS-Interpreter](https://github.com/NeilFraser/JS-Interpreter), then use source-maps to somehow reverse the transformation, but not sure exactly how to do that.

I even thought maybe the Chrome debugger extension API might help me (as devtools has most of what i need) but couldn't see any public methods that can help me with that.

Any ideas?